# backbone.js sync and storage optoñs

Tags: database, mobile, backbone.js

Starting out with backbone.js and getting fairly comfortable with the basics of structuring an app on the front end but find myself a little puzzled around using backbone sync and storing data.

While I'm aware that backbone.js is pretty flexible I'd like to know what the most natural and common data storage optoons are for simple backbone applicarions, ideally I'd be interested in options that would be mobile compatible, but mostly id like to know what others are using and how to grt started.

I've started exploring (though I'm a total noob with all of this) the following

- Couchdb and couchApps ?
- Maybe pouchdB for offline and sync with an online couchdb setup ?
- Mongodb ?
- Localstorage ? - not sure about this one  - limitations / support ect.

Couch and mongo both look great for apps that are online, read somewhere that couch could run on mobile ?  but I'm not sure if I read that wrong,

EDIT   - Firebase Looks like a great optional service for a 'backend-less' app as well but doesn't solve my concerns for offline, I suppose one could switch between localstorage and an online solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB and the associated [ecosystem](http://www.replication.io/) are certainly a great fit for sync (...replication in CouchDB parlance). Conflict handling, replication and offline operation were considered from the beginning and there are a number of datastores which can replicate with each other using the [CouchDB replication protocol](http://dataprotocols.org/couchdb-replication/).

As of writing, there are a few options for syncing data from a CouchDB instance (or compatible service such as [Cloudant](http://cloudant.com) or [IrisCouch](http://www.iriscouch.com/)) to a mobile device but the most mature libraries are [Couchbase Lite](http://www.couchbase.com/mobile) and [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/).

PouchDB can be used in the browser as well - under the hood it will use the most appropriate browser local storage option.

CouchDB itself isn't designed to run on mobile devices so I wouldn't recommend it. The key part is the replication protocol which allows synchronisation between datastores at different scales (mobile, desktop, web), each with appropriate implementations.

Comment: thanks for the great answer regarding CouchDB, I have read a few criticisms of it, which have made me hesitant but of everything I've looked at I like it the most, not quite sure about how to get it setup properly yet but I'll get there, I'm going to leave this question open for a while longer to see if I get any other opinions.

Comment: CouchDB itself can be tricky to run but you could use a DBaaS to relieve you of that. Couchbase Lite and PouchDB are both different beasts (the way they store and query data is different to CouchDB) so any criticisms of CouchDB likely don't apply there, though they will have their own issues of course. The CouchDB community is very friendly and helpful so if you have any trouble, be sure to make use of the mailing list or IRC channel.

Comment: thanks Will appreciate all the input, can you point me in the direction of any GOOD pouchDB / CouchDB tutorials / guides  - preferably that reference backbone ? (would you reccommend pouch over couchbase lite ?)

Comment: The CouchDB docs (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/tour.html) are a good starting point. There are a few backbone connectors https://github.com/janmonschke/backbone-couchdb is probably the most popular. I'd recommend PouchDB if you are going down a PhoneGap/Cordova route, otherwise Couchbase Lite probably makes more sense.

Comment: thanks again for all the info, I really like the look of couchDB and it definitely seems like a simple entry point for simple apps, I like the rich feature set that parse has, though it doesn't seem to do realtime very well,which firebase looks great for  though the feature doesn't seem as complete.  The BaaS providers offer quite a lot but the costing concerns me for small apps, and I like the idea of building out a small backend my self with couch and various other open tools.  Cheers.